# Extra Pre Chat Information for Messaging Session

Tags: chat, einstein-chatbot, embedded-services, messagingsession

i am facing an issue and I did not find any way to make this work
I am transitioning from the Embedded chat Service to the new Messaging in app and web created by salesforce.

With the embedded chat service we were using the extra pre-chat in order to feed our bot with extra information that look something like:

```
embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
  "label": "First Name",
  "value": "John",
  "displayToAgent": true
}, {
  "label": "Last Name",
  "value": "Doe",
  "displayToAgent": true
}, {
  "label": "Email",
  "value": "john.doe@salesforce.com",
  "displayToAgent": true
}];
```

I tried to find some documentation on the internet, but no way to find how to adapt this and pass extra information for the Messaging feature.
I tried to do

```
embeddedservice_bootstrap.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
              "label": "First Name",
              "value": "John",
              "displayToAgent": true
            }];
```

but this is not working .. any idea ?
thx you

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the concerned Salesforce Product team internally on your ask and got a confirmation that it’s not supported yet, you can’t pass anything to the new Messaging.

The goal will be to have parity with existing chat where appropriate, and the team is targeting to cover this feature in Spring'23(Safe Harbor). There is no workaround.

Recommend reviewing the other considerations listed in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.miaw_considerations_and_limitations.htm&type=5)

Comment: Are there any workarounds? I still do not get how salesforce can still release half-baked products feature and make us pay full price ...
Is it doable on the App ?

Comment: @Ben2pop I understand your concern. The Salesforce team is targeting to cover this feature in Spring'23(Safe Harbor). There is no workaround

Answer (score -3):

Please use  embeddedservice_bootstrap.prechatAPI.setHiddenPrechatFields
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/service/messaging-web/guide/pre-chat.html

Comment: Can you expand on this and post some of the releavnt content? Links tend to break over time so link-only answers usually get removed by the community